# How to alter/add column to json serde table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I had a table

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS XYZ.testtable (
x BIGINT,
y STRING,
z STRING
)
PARTITIONED BY (
      date string,
      hour  STRING
    ) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
        WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 'paths'='x, y, z')
        STORED AS TEXTFILE
        LOCATION 'testlocation/testtable'
```

with huge json data. I want to add one more column something like c to existing table so i tried

```
>1. alter table XYZ.testtable add columns (c STRING);

> 2.ALTER TABLE XYZ.testtable SET SERDEPROPERTIES ( 'paths'='x, y, z, c')
```

**but the c value which is present in json file coming as null.**

I tried drop and recreate table with 'c' column . it was working fine. can any one help how to alter jsonserde table to add coulmn.

Comment: I think you need to add the column by using `ALTER PARTITION`

Comment: @cricket_007, I am not trying to add partition i am trying to add columns

Comment: You're trying to add columns *within partitions*. For example, I think `ALTER TABLE PARTITION date='x', hour='y' ADD COLUMN ...`